# Realtek 8168 ethernet driver not working - Ubuntu Studio 16.10

Tags: networking, realtek

my network connection stopped working after some updates and I found there was a new driver for my Realtek 8168 card - new version of the driver is 8.044 - I've installed and loaded it as per every other version of this driver but it just doesn't want to work - any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or are there any logs that provide anything helpful?

Comment: Is secure boot disabled in your BIOS? In `terminal` show us the output of `dkms status` (edit into your question).